# How can I install my MAMP database in another computer?

Tags: mysql, mamp

I'm currently developing a Project which uses MAMP, phpMyAdmin and such.
I will need to deliver the materials and instructions to my teachers so they can "duplicate" the server and run on their machines.

I know about the folder htdocs which contains my scripts but I have no idea where the database I created with all the columns and rows is located.

Besides htdocs, what files do I need to send to my teachers so they can replicate my localhost server exactly as it is now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your familiarity and skill level.  I would certainly avoid trying to copy the MySQL file data across - it's not really designed for that purpose.

Essentially, the best option is to create a `.sql` file dump of the database.  As you're using a "stack", it doesn't sound likely you'd be using a linux console (for `mysqldump`), so your options are:

a) **Use a PHP script**

You could set up and execute a PHP script that will do the above.

```
$database = 'db';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';
$host = 'localhost';
$dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/myDB.sql';

echo "Dumping DB to {$dir}";
exec("mysqldump --user={$user} --password={$pass} --host={$host} {$database} --result-file={$dir} 2>&1");
```

b) **Use a DB GUI**

Using something like HeidiSQL, you can connect to your DB and then 'Export' it using the Table tools ('Export database as SQL'), e.g.
[image]

You could then use the resulting `.sql` file from either scenario to populate the other user's MySQL databases - depending on the size, phpMyAdmin should be able to handle it.

Comment: Does method #1 work for multiple databases in MAMP?

Comment: @YCode you can duplicate it for as many as you like - simply change the DB name.  It's been nearly 3 years now and I don't do much with PHP any more, so barely recognise the answer to be honest :D

Comment: :-) I'm sure someone who knows PHP can work with it. In my case, it's mostly WordPress databases, so I'll use a migration tool instead. It's a hassle, but guaranteed to work. Thanks!